# C++ short array 'reversed' when casted to integer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

As a newbie in C++ I've been playing around with pointers a bit. I have written the following code to interpret a short array as an integer:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    short array[2] = {10, 9};

    short* pointer = array;
    std::cout << pointer << ": " << *pointer << std::endl;
    // 0xffffcbdc: 10

    pointer++;
    std::cout << pointer << ": " << *pointer << std::endl;
    // 0xffffcbde: 9

    int* pointer2 = (int*) array;
    std::cout << pointer2 << ": " << *pointer2 << std::endl;
    // 0xffffcbdc: 589834
}
```

**Why is the value of the integer 589'834 (0009 000A) and not 655'369 (000A 0009)?**

From the printed pointer addresses it looks like the array is in order in memory, why does casting to integer change that?

Comment: Look up big-endian. And little-endian.

Comment: The "Undefined Behavior" police are out in force today -- I dare not post an answer.

Comment: First, your integer representations as hex-value are wrong: 589'834 == 0x0009'000A and 655'369 == 0x000A'0009. Despite your int-pointer conversion is undefined behavior, your CPU seems to use "Little Endian" which means lower bytes are stored at lower memory addresses. In "Big Endian" higher bytes are stored at lower memory addresses. Using "Little Endian", no padding and 16-bit short ints your array has the following layout in memory: 0A 00 09 00. Using "Big Endian" instead, the memory looks like 00 0A 00 09.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behavior is undefined:

```
int* pointer2 = (int*) array;
```

You are allowed to reinterpret a pointer to `T1` as a pointer to `T2` only if alignment requirements of `T2` are the same or less strict than alignment requirements of `T1` ([see reference for more details](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)). Since alignment requirements for `int` are stricter than alignment requirements for `short`, your pointer re-interpretation is invalid.

Note that re-interpreting a pointer to `int` as a pointer to `short` would be valid.

**Note:** Since behavior is undefined, your program could do anything, including printing incorrect values or even crashing. However, the most likely reason for the behavior that you see is that your system stores higher bytes of an integer at lower addresses. This is one of two common options: the second one is to store higher bytes at higher addresses. These two options are called *endianness*. [More information on it is here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: "Note that re-interpreting a pointer to int as a pointer to short would be valid." i want to add, that you may not deference the pointer because of strict aliasing rules.

Answer (score 3):

What you do is undefined behaviour, as you are violating the strict aliasing rule. Therefore, don't bother about any output you get from it.

Comment: It's not undefined if you understand how integers are stored. It's undefined at the source code level but deterministic at the CPU level.

Comment: @nicomp It is undefined, in the sense that the compiler is allowed to do anything with code. If the code produce any result at all it is purely coincidental and may change between versions of the compiler or even between invocations of the program.

Comment: It's only deterministic if you assume no compiler optimizations happen, and your compiler isn't trying to be mean on purpose. UB is not deterministic by definition.

Comment: @nicomp Any statements on endianess is pure speculation. It might be the reason for this behaviour, but that is nothing you can rely on.

Comment: People need to stop trying to rationalise/rehabilitate UB. Code that does things the language doesn't guarantee is bad, and that's the end of it. It's not interesting to endlessly speculate about how _it'll probably be fine_, _it happens to work because of X_, etc.

Comment: @underscore_d Nonsense. This issues is endlessly interesting. No field of study focuses solely on positive outcomes.

Comment: @underscore_d it's not about speculating wether it is fine to use such code, it's clearly not fine. It's about learning about the underlying system.

Comment: @kalsowerus Your question doesn't contain any information on that. For this, you would have had to ask why your specific system/compiler (which you did not mention) is yielding this result. Again: UB stays UB.

Comment: @Jodocus Evidently OP *cannot* ask why his specific compiler is yielding the result because it's UB and we can't discuss that.

Comment: @nicomp You are contradicting yourself.